# failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET while connecting to mqtt using ng2-mqtt

Tags: angular, mqtt

While connecting to `mqtt` using `ng2-mqtt (paho)` I'm getting the below error .

> mqttws31.js:979 WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://bfwirisnandi.in:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket
>   handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: What makes you think that you can use Websockets with port 1883? That is normally the Native MQTT port.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment. What broker are you using and how is it configured.  Just posting an error message with no other information is not all that helpful. Please read the doc on what a good question should contain: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is my code

```
this._client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("abcd.in", 8000,"efrfrefrefer");
this._client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
this._client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
var options = {
useSSL: false,
userName: "onlysub",
password: "OsubALL",
onSuccess:onConnect,
onFailure:doFail
}
this._client.connect(options);
function onConnect() {
console.log("onConnect");
this._client.subscribe("/dgvf/v1c");
}
function doFail(e){
console.log(e);
}
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
}
}
function onMessageArrived(message) {
console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
```